# Best practices - Parsing XML API response - Python 3

Tags: python, xml, xpath, elementtree

I have referenced several guides, but I'm still finding it difficult to wrap my head around this (Python newb):

- /docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html
- /effbot.org/zone/element-xpath.htm

[xml output example](http://prntscr.com/gcyslt)

The intent is to retrieve the zipcode text value; however, I haven't done this before and from referencing the guides, I want the output of the following xpath:

```
/SearchResults:searchresults[@xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
instance"]/response/results/result/address/zipcode/text()
```

Here's an example of what's working from a local file:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse(<destination_of_xml>.xml')

for elem in tree.iterfind('/response/results/result/address/zipcode'):
    print(elem.tag, elem.text)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
output: 
zipcode {90292}
zipcode {90292}
...
```

What's good practice in this instance to retrieve zipcode values and account for any schema changes in the future (i.e. iterate through XML until finding the element zipcode)? Are there better solutions to this?

Comment: I doubt there's a truly general answer. Zipcodes won't necessarily bear the tag `zipcode` because xml allows any sort of name for them. You could look for a legal five-digit zipcode value but then you'd have to be alert for the presence of the longer version of the zipcodes. Beyond that, one entry for a business might contain two or more zipcodes. Which one would you accept? Or am I missing the point of your question?

Comment: Well, in this instance, I'm assuming that from this xml source, zipcodes will always bear the tag 'zipcode'; however, they might not always be nested under /response/results/result/address/zipcode - say, the host updates something and zipcodes are located under /response/results/result/zipcodes instead - how would I account for that?

Comment: If an answer meets your requirements please mark it 'accepted'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to know about xpath expressions.

I'm using the lxml library to parse a simpler xml hierarchy. I don't need to know what's above the `zipcode` element because I can write an xpath expression that says, in effect, look anywhere from the top of the document for `zipcode` elements (note, plural): `.//zipcode`. This yields the element. Now that I have them, since I know there's just one, I select the 'first', get its `text` and strip off leading and trailing blanks.

Providing that the name of the element remains unchanged ...

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> tree = etree.fromstring('''\
... <company>
...     <name>XYZ</name>
...     <industry>chemicals</industry>
...     <address>
...         <street>
...             14234 Onyx Drive West
...         </street>
...         <city>
...             Ainslie
...         </city>
...         <state>
...             Idaho
...         </state>
...         <zipcode>
...             87734
...         </zipcode>
...     </address>
... </company>''')
>>> tree.xpath('.//zipcode')
[<Element zipcode at 0xb5e9c8>]

>>> tree.xpath('.//zipcode')[0].text.strip()
'87734'
```